# How to remove all elements in row that larger than elements in other column or row using Pandas or NumPy

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a matrix

```
 1   1   5  -6
 5   3   7   8
-5   0  -1   3
-1   1   1   8
```

I need to remove the 1st column because all it's elements is less than 3rd column. And remove 1st and 3rd rows.
As I understand, I need to make a bool vector with information about removing row/column. Main problem is make a vector

Comment: What do you mean by "1st column because all it's elements is less than 3rd column."? If it is elementwise, your statement is false. is it the sum you are referring to? Why remove 1st and 3rd rows?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes all elements of 1st column is less than relevant elements of 3rd column
all elements 1st row is less than relevant elements in 2nd row. I've implemented this but maybe that pandas can do it better

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented, but maybe pandas can do it shorter:

```
def reduce(df):
    while True:
        size = df.size
        df = reduce_by_cols(df)
        df = reduce_by_rows(df)
        if size == df.size:
            break
    return df


def is_row_larger_than_other(row1, row2):
    for index_, row1_ in row1.items():
        if row1[index_] < row2[index_]:
            return False
    return True


def reduce_by_rows(df):
    for index_, row in df.iterrows():
        for index, row1 in df.iterrows():
            if is_row_larger_than_other(row, row1) & (index != index_) & (index_ in df.index):
                df.drop(index_, inplace=True)
    return df


def reduce_by_cols(df):
    s = pd.Series()
    for index_, row in df.iteritems():
        for index, row1 in df.iteritems():
            if is_row_larger_than_other(row, row1) & (index != index_) & (index_ in df):
                s["index_"] = index_
    df.drop(s, axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
```